# iPadの実機ビルドで、account, profiles エラー

Tags: swift, xcode

中古で購入したiPad実機を接続して、実機ビルドをした所、
以下のエラーが出て、ビルドが失敗してしまいます。

```
No account for team "ZW9X253P4S". Add a new account in the Accounts preference pane or verify that your accounts have valid credentials.

No profiles for 'jp.co.****.AIForceReceptionAppDevelop' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'jp.co.****.AIForceReceptionAppDevelop'.
```

認証周りのエラーだと思うのですが、
認証に詳しくないので、困っております。

iPad実機は、AppleDevelopCenterにUDIDを登録済みです。
"ZW9X253P4S"というチームは作成していません。
Signingは、「Automatically manage signing」にチェックを入れております。

どなたか詳しい方、ご教授お願いできませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自分のアカウントをクライアント様のグループに登録してもらうことで、
解決出来ました。